# Remove blank lines between rows while exporting Crystal Report to .csv file

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Below are the screen shots one is the Crystal Report and other the exported .csv file.
[image]
[image]

As you can see in the .csv file after each  row there is a blank line.I have searched for a solution but no luck. Can anyone let me know how to get the output without the blank lines between rows.

Comment: CSV files don't have formatting like that... Did you export this as an Excel file and then just change the file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical space between lines you have in the report is most likely interpreted as an empty row when you export it to csv. Try reducing the vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports exports are temperamental.  Try TTX format.